# Pass Resoure Parameter - Xamarin.Auth

Tags: xamarin, printer-control-language, xamarin.auth

Is there anyway to pass in a resource parameter when using Xamarin.Auth?

I am using the Microsoft Login Provider to login, however the token that gets generated results in a 401 when I use the token to access the API (hosted on Azure).

Thanks in advance